# java String to an object

Tags: java, string, object

I want to convert a `String` to an object. I looked for related topics but could not find an answer. My code is:

```
amountShip = 5;
String name = ReadConsole.nextString(); //-->variabe of the object "Player"
gamers[i] = Player.String2Object(name, 0);

Player String2Object(String name, int amountShip) {
   Object o = name;
   Player temp = (Player)o;
   temp = new Player(name, amountShip);
   return temp;             
}

class Player {
    Player (String name, int amountShip) {
        name = name;
        ships = amountShip;
    }
    Player pl = new Player(String name, int amountShip);
}
```

it says

> java.lang.String cannot be cast to Gameobjects.Player

My intention is to create 2 Player-objects with different instance names dynamically. If for example somebody types in "3", i want to create

```
Player p1 = new Player(x,y);
Player p2 = new Player(x,y);
Player p3 = new Player(x,y);
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `Object o = name;Player temp = (Player)o;` What do you think this does? If you answer it then you resolved your problem.

Comment: Java is great, but it can't do magic! Nevertheless, you should really fix formatting and give more information (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess all you want is to make it like this?

```
Player String2Object(String name, int amountShip) {
    return new Player(name, amountShip);
}
```

Or maybe simply

```
gamers[i] = new Player(name, 0);
```

instead of

```
gamers[i] = Player.String2Object(name, 0);
```

Another approach is to read line from console (or file) and extract `name` and `amountShip` with `String.split` function for example.

**EDIT:**

You can not dynamically create instances like in your question. But you can create array `Player[]` like this

```
// n is some int entered by user.
Player[] players = new Player[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    players[i] = new Player(x, y);
}
```

And then get the i-th player like this (assume that class `Player` have `getName` method)

```
players[i].getName();
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` can't be converted to 'Spieler' by casting. Instead you could either use `Serialization`, or create a method to parse the attributes of the object from some given input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert a `String` to an object because a `String` IS an object by deafault so the casting is not needed. You can do the following:

```
Player String2Object(String name, int amountShip) {
    Player temp = new Player(name, amountShip);
    return temp;             
}
```

If you ask yourself why your code is not working the way it is that's because you are trying to cast a `String` into a `Player`. Your object `o` points to a `String` so when you try to do `(Player)o` you are trying to cast a string into a `Player` and they share no relation between them.